# CSS:How can I set the text in the block element center of vertical direction

Tags: css, inline, vertical-alignment

The point is that I have set `vertical-align: center` property

I have a `p`:

```
<p><span>Hello World</span></p>​

p{
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px black solid;
}
span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/yhLqV/2/

I want the text in the paragraph could be center at both vertical and horizontal direction

but the `span`'s `vertical-align` property doesn't work?Why?

I get some advises about set the `line-height` equal to the parent's height, it works only when there is only one line in the parent box.

How can I achieve my goal(may be I can use some css3 property)? Set the inner element at the center of parent vertical direction

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but with some lite work this will do http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can achieve your desired results through the mentioned below **CSS** code :-

You can give the `display:table` to the `parent` and `display:table-cell; & vertical-align:middle;`  to the `Child` than you will be to get your desired results as mentioning below the **CSS** & **Demo link...**

**CSS**

```
p{
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px black solid;
    display:table;

}
span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**here is the demo** :- http://jsfiddle.net/yhLqV/5/

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your CSS [[Working fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/yhLqV/4/):

```
`   border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50% auto;
    width: 200px;`
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to dig in to properties like display: table, table-cell, table-row.
I believe those are ie8 and above.
so you can imitate table behavior with your html organization.

html is same...

css will be

```
p{
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px black solid;
    display:table;
}
span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

​fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhLqV/6/